# Как исправить баг когда я рисую кистью на резких поворотах?

Tags: javascript, canvas

У меня есть вот такой код

```js
can = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
can.width = 500; 
can.height = 500; 

var ctx = can.getContext('2d'); //Выбрать пространство

//Функция рисования
$( "#canvas" ).dblclick(function() {
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();//Заполнение 
  ctx.beginPath();
});

can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Цвет 
  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY); //Координаты линий
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;//Толщина линий
  ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2);  //Круг
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

```css
#canvas{
     background-color:#46bba4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;"></canvas>
```

И в последствий вопрос 
почему кисть на резких поворотах уносить в сторону
И почему при изменений размера в can.width; и can.height; 
Центр кисти уходит куда то в сторону от курсора
Может ли кто помочь решить проблему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Вы рисуете последовательно в рамках одного кадра, наверное это возможно, однако  но я сделал по другому, смотрите мой пример, я собираю точки в массивы и перерисовываю каждый раз весь кадр.

А в Вашем случае получается что все линии (и кругов и линии которую Вы рисуете)рисуются как части одной линии, отсюда и поведение, которое Вы не ожидаете

2. При резких поворотах появляется сильный вылет у `miter` (тип соединения участков кривой, который стоит по умолчанию для рисования линий на канве), тип можно поменять на `round` и соединения будет закругленные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Вы не учитываете положение канвы на экране при расчете координат кликов.
4. Для учета скролла при расчете координат используйте `e.pageX` и `e.pageY`

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
can.width = 500; 
can.height = 500; 
let x, y;
var ctx = can.getContext('2d'); //Выбрать пространство
let pts = [[]];

$( "#canvas" ).dblclick(function() {
  pts[pts.length-1].pop(); //удалим повторную точку
  pts.push([]) // новая коллекция точек
  repaint();
});

can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  pts[pts.length-1].push([
    e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
    e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop
  ]);
  repaint();
});

function repaint(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height)
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Цвет 
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;//Толщина линий
  ctx.lineJoin = "round";
  
  // рисуем фигуры
  pts.forEach((shape, j)=> {
    ctx.beginPath();
    shape.forEach((p, i) => {
      ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);
    })
    if(j !== pts.length-1){ 
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  })
  
  // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
  pts[pts.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(...p, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2);  //Круг
    ctx.stroke();
  })
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color:#46bba4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;"></canvas>
```