# рисование мышью canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Есть проблема при рисовании юзером 4 угольной формы на canvas, когда ведешь мышью рисуется форма stroke и она очищается методом clearRect, но когда начинаешь вести во внутрь этого же 4 угольника он перестает его чистить и оставляет внутри черные линии, когда ведешь опять в том направлении он опять очищает внутреннее пространство.Мне нужно чтобы новые квадраты не отрисовывались и при нажатии мыши не удалялся первый и единственный 4-х угольник. Как мне правильно передать чтобы , пользователь рисовал только 1 квадрат нужных ему размеров и мог отчистить canvas только с помощью кнопки "отчистить" ?  Может сказано запутано, но это так!

1. Почему это происходит?
2. Как это исправить?

вот весь код:

```js
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var canvas, context, tool;

    function init() {
      // Находим canvas элемент
      canvas = document.getElementById('tablet');



      if (!canvas) {
        alert('Ошибка! Canvas элемент не найден!');
        return;
      }

      if (!canvas.getContext) {
        alert('Ошибка: canvas.getContext не существует!');
        return;
      }

      // Получаем 2D canvas context.
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.strockeStyle = '#4caf50';
      if (!context) {
        alert('Ошибка: getContext! не существует');
        return;
      }
      //
      tool = new tool_rect();
      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
    }

    // Здесь мы будем ловить движения мыши и отрисовывать прямоугольньник
    function tool_rect() {
      var tool = this;
      this.started = false;


      this.mousedown = function(ev) {

        tool.started = true;
        tool.x0 = ev._x;
        tool.y0 = ev._y;
      };

      this.mousemove = function(ev) {
        if (!tool.started) {
          return;
        }
        // высчитываем прямоугольник по зажатой мышки и координаты при ее ведении по холсту
        var x = Math.min(ev._x, tool.x0),
          y = Math.min(ev._y, tool.y0),
          w = Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
          h = Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0);





        context.clearRect(x, y, w, h); // стирает старый прямоугольник при попытки создать новый

        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }, false)


        if (!w || !h) {
          return;


        }

        context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h); // создание прямоугольника без заливки согласно переданным параметром от мышки

      };


      this.mouseup = function(ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
          tool.mousemove(ev);
          tool.started = false;


        }
      };
    }

    // Эта функция определяет позицию курсора относительно холста
    function ev_canvas(ev) {
      if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
        ev._x = ev.layerX;
        ev._y = ev.layerY;
      } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
        ev._x = ev.offsetX;
        ev._y = ev.offsetY;
      }

      // Вызываем обработчик события tool
      var func = tool[ev.type];
      if (func) {
        func(ev);
      }
    }

    init();

  }, false);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.rectangle {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Video Streaming</h1>

<div style="display:flex; margin:0 45%">

  <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  <img style="" src="{{ url_for('video_feed2') }}">

  <canvas id='tablet' height='150' width='100' style="
                    border: 1px solid red;
                    position: relative;
                    right: 101px;">
        </canvas>
  <input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Очистить" />
</div>
```

Comment: Сделайте сниппет из своего кода

Comment: Вы пересчитали координаты и передали `context.clearRect(x, y, w, h);` новые координаты. Поэтому в обратку это не работает т.к. новый прямоугольник не покрывает полностью старый.

Comment: Как написал Stranger in the Q, можно очищать всю канву. Если нужно оставить старые квадратики - храните их значение в массиве и каждый раз перерисовывайте

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо оперативную реакцию. Мне нужно чтобы новые квадраты не отрисовывались и при нажатии мыши не удалялся первый и единственный 4-х угольник. Как мне правильно передать чтобы , пользователь рисовал только 1 квадрат нужных ему размеров и мог отчистить canvas только с помощью кнопки "отчистить" ?

Comment: @HiddenFox29 повторно квадрат нарисовать можно только после "очистить"

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Привет! Объясни мне пожалуйста, как и чем регулируется на холсте(canvas) опция повторного рисования фигур без стирания их с холста и как активируется ограничение.

Comment: @HiddenFox29 такой встроенной функции нет, нужно хранить информацию о фигурах и рисовать их каждый кадр

Comment: @Stranger in the в массиве? или как ? есть какой нибудь источник для глубокого изучения детали ? кругом поверхностно все...

Comment: @HiddenFox29 я искал ответ :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366 тут немного про другое вопрос, но в ответе есть код, который делает то о чем я говорил

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Это очень глубоко)) Пример: на холсте я рисую мышью линию от а к б линия отрисовывается после отпускания кнопки мыши , я хочу нарисовать еще одну линию не стирая пред идущею, и не могу догнать как мне это сделать!

Comment: @HiddenFox29 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/979140/188366

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97811/discussion-between-hiddenfox29-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: Привет!
@Stranger in the Q Тебе приходилось отрисовывать на канвас по координатам из файла json?

Comment: @HiddenFox29 хай, а в чем трудность?

Comment: Stranger in the Q Пользователь отрисовывает фигуры на канвас(с помощью точек из того примера , что ты мне подсказал) и нужные координаты сохраняет в фаил json, я хочу сделать кнопку чтобы после нажатия можно было от рисовать сохраненные координаты обратно, если пользователь отчистил холст!

Comment: я просто понять не могу мне как данные обратно подавать как словарь(ключ:значение) или как массив точек?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Здравствуйте, посмотрите пожалуйста мой вопрос, помогите дельным советом. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1020284/canvas-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82

Comment: @HiddenFox29 вечером состряпаю ответ

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы очищаете кусочек канвы, меньше чем прямоугольник, очищайте всю канву:

```
 // стирает старый прямоугольник при попытки создать новый
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

UPD: судя по тому что я понял из вопроса добавил еще один флаг в код. `tool.deactivated`, который устанавливается когда нарисован прямоугольник и сбрасывается по кнопке очистить. так же слушатель на `mouseup` я повесил не на канву а на документ, чтобы отлавливать завершение рисования вне канвы.

```js
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var canvas, context, tool;

    function init() {
      // Находим canvas элемент
      canvas = document.getElementById('tablet');

      if (!canvas) {
        alert('Ошибка! Canvas элемент не найден!');
        return;
      }

      if (!canvas.getContext) {
        alert('Ошибка: canvas.getContext не существует!');
        return;
      }

      // Получаем 2D canvas context.
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.strokeStyle = '#4caf50';
      if (!context) {
        alert('Ошибка: getContext! не существует');
        return;
      }
      //
      tool = new tool_rect();
      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
      addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
    }

    // Здесь мы будем ловить движения мыши и отрисовывать прямоугольньник
    function tool_rect() {
      var tool = this;
      this.started = false;

      this.mousedown = function(ev) {
        if (tool.deactivated) 
          return;
        tool.started = true;
        tool.x0 = ev._x;
        tool.y0 = ev._y;
      };

      this.mousemove = function(ev) {
        if (!tool.started || tool.deactivated) {
          return;
        }
        // высчитываем прямоугольник по зажатой мышки и координаты при ее ведении по холсту
        var x = Math.min(ev._x, tool.x0),
          y = Math.min(ev._y, tool.y0),
          w = Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
          h = Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0);

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // стирает старый прямоугольник при попытки создать новый

        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          tool.deactivated = false;
          clear.setAttribute('disabled', 'true')
        }, false)


        if (!w || !h) {
          return;
        }

        context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h); // создание прямоугольника без заливки согласно переданным параметром от мышки
      };

      this.mouseup = function(ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
          tool.started = false;
          tool.deactivated = true;
          clear.disabled = false;
        }
      };
    }

    // Эта функция определяет позицию курсора относительно холста
    function ev_canvas(ev) {
      if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
        ev._x = ev.layerX;
        ev._y = ev.layerY;
      } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
        ev._x = ev.offsetX;
        ev._y = ev.offsetY;
      }

      // Вызываем обработчик события tool
      var func = tool[ev.type];
      if (func) {
        func(ev);
      }
    }

    init();

  }, false);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.rectangle {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Video Streaming</h1>
<div style="display:flex; margin:0 45%">
  <canvas id='tablet' height='150' width='100' style="border: 1px solid red;position: relative;right: 101px;"></canvas>
  <input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Очистить" disabled/>
</div>
```

Comment: Stranger in the Q,  Спасибо тебе большое! ты просто гений!!))

Comment: @HiddenFox29 Нет проблем, обращайтесь

Comment: Пожалуйста, посоветуй какой нибудь дельный ресурс по изучению js и ты какому фремворку отдаешь предпочтения в Vue или React, может что-то иное, я только в самом начале изучения,  почту за честь твой совет! Спасибо!

Comment: @HiddenFox29 если честно - фреймворк я ни один не люблю. хороший ресурс https://learn.javascript.ru