# canvas отрисовка сохраненных координат

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть приложение по выделению областей полигонами, пользователь может сохранять координаты в localStorage и по нажатию кнопки отрисовывать их снова.

Проблема 1: после отрисовки сохраненных координат фигура появившиеся на холсте исчезнет(сотрется), при первом нажатии мыши, если пользователь продолжит рисовать рядом с отрисовавшейся фигурой полигон. Этого быть не должно. Это происходит из-за установки от чистки canvas при перерисовки координат.

Проблема 2: если я убираю от чистку проблема 1 решается, но фигуры перестают быть прозрачными в процессе рисования и закрашивают полностью участок холста.

Как решить? пожалуйста объясните как это работает и как это исправить.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Streaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

</head>

<body>

    <h1></h1>

    <div class="main_cont">



        <img class="img-1" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
        <canvas id='canvas' height='500' width='500' style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>

        <input type = "button" id = "clear" name = "clear" value = "Очистить холст" />
        <button id = "clearButton">Очистить input</button>
        <button id = "addButton">Показать координаты</button>
        <button id = "repainButton">Отрисовать сохранившиеся</button>
        <button id = "saveCoord">Сохранить координаты</button>

        <form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
        <p>
            <label class="rect_coord" for="coordinates">Coordinates camera</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="rect_coord" name="coordinates" required><br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="button2" style='margin-top:20px;' type="submit" name="Save" >
        </p>

        </form>


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


//======================================================================================================
        let can = document.getElementById('canvas');
                can.width = 500;
                can.height = 500;
                let x, y;
                let ctx = can.getContext('2d'); //Выбрать пространство
                let pts = [[]];
                let coordinats;
                let new_array = [];
                let upcomingFigure = [];
                let data;
                var clearCoordinat;
//======================================================================================================
                // убирает выделение холста синим цветом при двойном нажатии мыши
                document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
//======================================================================================================
                // отрисовывает сохраненные координаты фигур
                document.getElementById('repainButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    // извлекаем данные из localstorege
                    data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
                    // data[data.length-1].pop(); //удалим повторную точку
                    console.info('ЭТО data', data)
                    data.push([]) // новая коллекция точек
                    repaintButton(); // вызываев функцию для отрисовки с кнопки


                    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                      });
                  },false)
//======================================================================================================
                // замыкаение и отрисовка фигуры по двойному клику вызовом func(repaint)
                $( "#canvas" ).dblclick(function() {
                  pts[pts.length-1].pop(); //удалим повторную точку
                  pts.push([]) // новая коллекция точек
                  repaint();
                  coordinats = pts
//======================================================================================================
                // добавление в input координат в строке JSON
                  remove_empty_str = function(coordinats) {
                              new_array = [];

                              console.log(new_array)
                              for (ii = 0, len = coordinats.length; ii < len; ii++) {
                                item = coordinats[ii];
                                if (item !== "" || item !== null || item !== 0) {
                                  new_array.push(item);
                              };
                                if (new_array.length > 2 || new_array[0].length === 1){
                                  upcomingFigure = new_array.splice(0, 1);
                                   if (upcomingFigure[0].lenght === 1) {
                                    upcomingFigure.splice(0, 1)
                                };

                              };
                            }
                              return new_array;
                              return upcomingFigure;
                            };
                              newIDs = remove_empty_str(coordinats);
                                clearCoordinat = pts;
                              document.getElementById('saveCoord').onclick = function(event) {
                                window.localStorage.setItem('storeObj', JSON.stringify(clearCoordinat));
                              }

                              let res = Array.from(new Set(new_array.flat()));

                              document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = function(event) {
                                if (res.length !==1 || res[0].length !== 2){
                                  document.getElementById('rect_coord').value = JSON.stringify(res)// поле заполнения координатами


                                  // JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));

                                  return coordinats
                              };
                            }


                             // отчистка поля input с кнопки
                              document.getElementById('clearButton').onclick = function(event) {
                                document.getElementById("rect_coord").value = null;
                                window.localStorage.removeItem('storeObj');
                            }

                });
//=======================================================================================================
                // события нажатия мыши и добавления координат в массив
                can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
                  pts[pts.length-1].push([
                    e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
                    e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop
                  ]);
                  repaint();
                [e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft, e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop]

                });
//=======================================================================================================
                // перерисовка холста и отрисовка фигуры по точкам из массива
                function repaint(){
                  if (repaintButton){
                  ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height)
                }
                  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // прозрачность
                  ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Цвет
                  ctx.lineWidth = 5;//Толщина линий
                  ctx.lineJoin = "miter"; // закругленность соединений линий

                  // рисуем фигуры
                    pts.forEach((shape, j)=> {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                      ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);

                    })
                    if(j !== pts.length-1){
                      ctx.fill();
                      ctx.closePath();
                    }
                    ctx.stroke();
                  })

                  // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
                  pts[pts.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(...p, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2);  //Круг
                    ctx.stroke();

                  })

                  // кнопка очистки canvas
                  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                        return pts = [[]];// отчищаю массив с точками для отрисовки фигуры
                }, false)
            }
//======================================================================================================
              // получаем асинхронный запрос к локальному файлу file.json
              function readTextFile(path_to_file, callback) {
                  let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                  rawFile.open("GET", path_to_file, true);
                  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                          callback(rawFile.responseText);
                      }
                  }
                  rawFile.send(null);
              }

              //usage:
              readTextFile("http://localhost:5000/static/json/coord.json", function(text){
                  var file_data = JSON.parse(text);
                  console.log(file_data);
              });

//======================================================================================================
              // функция для отрисовки из сохраненых координат в фаиле file.json
              function repaintButton(){
                  // ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);

                  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // прозрачность
                  ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Цвет
                  ctx.lineWidth = 5;//Толщина линий
                  ctx.lineJoin = "miter"; // закругленность соединений линий

                  // рисуем фигуры
                    data.forEach((shape, j)=> {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                      ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);

                    })
                    if(j !== data.length-1){
                      ctx.fill();
                      ctx.closePath();
                    }
                    ctx.stroke();
                  })

                  // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
                  data[data.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(...p, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2);  //Круг
                    ctx.stroke();

                  })
                }
//=======================================================================================================


    </script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='json/coord.json') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Спасибо большое! Столько времени провел, пытаясь разобраться в этом !

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Если у вас появится время вы мог ли бы от ценить мой код и указать на ошибки которые нужно исправить или моменты которые не приемлемы при написании. Я открыт для любой критики, если вам будет не трудно. За ранее спасибо за все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При восстановлении из localstorage необходимо заменить массив фигур которые сейчас рисуются (переменная `pts`) на тот который считан:

```
    pts = data;  /// я изменил одну эту строчку (№69)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Streaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

</head>

<body>

<h1></h1>

<div class="main_cont">



    <img class="img-1" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    <canvas id='canvas' height='500' width='500' style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>

    <input type = "button" id = "clear" name = "clear" value = "Очистить холст" />
    <button id = "clearButton">Очистить input</button>
    <button id = "addButton">Показать координаты</button>
    <button id = "repainButton">Отрисовать сохранившиеся</button>
    <button id = "saveCoord">Сохранить координаты</button>

    <form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
        <p>
            <label class="rect_coord" for="coordinates">Coordinates camera</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="rect_coord" name="coordinates" required><br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="button2" style='margin-top:20px;' type="submit" name="Save" >
        </p>

    </form>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


    //======================================================================================================
    let can = document.getElementById('canvas');
    can.width = 500;
    can.height = 500;
    let x, y;
    let ctx = can.getContext('2d'); //Выбрать пространство
    let pts = [[]];
    let coordinats;
    let new_array = [];
    let upcomingFigure = [];
    let data;
    var clearCoordinat;
    //======================================================================================================
    // убирает выделение холста синим цветом при двойном нажатии мыши
    document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
    //======================================================================================================
    // отрисовывает сохраненные координаты фигур
    document.getElementById('repainButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // извлекаем данные из localstorege
        data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
        // data[data.length-1].pop(); //удалим повторную точку
        console.info('ЭТО data', data)
        pts = data // новая коллекция точек /// я изменил одну эту строчку
        repaintButton(); // вызываев функцию для отрисовки с кнопки


        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });
    },false)
    //======================================================================================================
    // замыкаение и отрисовка фигуры по двойному клику вызовом func(repaint)
    $( "#canvas" ).dblclick(function() {
        pts[pts.length-1].pop(); //удалим повторную точку
        pts.push([]) // новая коллекция точек
        repaint();
        coordinats = pts
//======================================================================================================
        // добавление в input координат в строке JSON
        remove_empty_str = function(coordinats) {
            new_array = [];

            console.log(new_array)
            for (ii = 0, len = coordinats.length; ii < len; ii++) {
                item = coordinats[ii];
                if (item !== "" || item !== null || item !== 0) {
                    new_array.push(item);
                };
                if (new_array.length > 2 || new_array[0].length === 1){
                    upcomingFigure = new_array.splice(0, 1);
                    if (upcomingFigure[0].lenght === 1) {
                        upcomingFigure.splice(0, 1)
                    };

                };
            }
            return new_array;
            return upcomingFigure;
        };
        newIDs = remove_empty_str(coordinats);
        clearCoordinat = pts;
        document.getElementById('saveCoord').onclick = function(event) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('storeObj', JSON.stringify(clearCoordinat));
        }

        let res = Array.from(new Set(new_array.flat()));

        document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = function(event) {
            if (res.length !==1 || res[0].length !== 2){
                document.getElementById('rect_coord').value = JSON.stringify(res)// поле заполнения координатами


                // JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));

                return coordinats
            };
        }


        // отчистка поля input с кнопки
        document.getElementById('clearButton').onclick = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("rect_coord").value = null;
            window.localStorage.removeItem('storeObj');
        }

    });
    //=======================================================================================================
    // события нажатия мыши и добавления координат в массив
    can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
        pts[pts.length-1].push([
            e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
            e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop
        ]);
        repaint();
        [e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft, e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop]

    });
    //=======================================================================================================
    // перерисовка холста и отрисовка фигуры по точкам из массива
    function repaint(){
        if (repaintButton){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height)
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // прозрачность
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Цвет
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;//Толщина линий
        ctx.lineJoin = "miter"; // закругленность соединений линий

        // рисуем фигуры
        pts.forEach((shape, j)=> {
            ctx.beginPath();
            shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);

            })
            if(j !== pts.length-1){
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        })

        // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
        pts[pts.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(...p, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2);  //Круг
            ctx.stroke();

        })

        // кнопка очистки canvas
        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            return pts = [[]];// отчищаю массив с точками для отрисовки фигуры
        }, false)
    }
    //======================================================================================================
    // получаем асинхронный запрос к локальному файлу file.json
    function readTextFile(path_to_file, callback) {
        let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        rawFile.open("GET", path_to_file, true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                callback(rawFile.responseText);
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    //usage:
    readTextFile("http://localhost:5000/static/json/coord.json", function(text){
        var file_data = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log(file_data);
    });

    //======================================================================================================
    // функция для отрисовки из сохраненых координат в фаиле file.json
    function repaintButton(){
        // ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // прозрачность
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Цвет
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;//Толщина линий
        ctx.lineJoin = "miter"; // закругленность соединений линий

        // рисуем фигуры
        data.forEach((shape, j)=> {
            ctx.beginPath();
            shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);

            })
            if(j !== data.length-1){
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        })

        // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
        data[data.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(...p, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2);  //Круг
            ctx.stroke();

        })
    }
    //=======================================================================================================


</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='json/coord.json') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```